# Can search(r'(ab)+', "ababababab") match all the characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I found that `findall(r'(ab)+', "ababababab")`  can only match the ["ab"]

```
>>> re.findall(r'(ab)+', "ababababab")
['ab']
```

i just know that using `r'(?:ab)+'` can match all the characters

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:ab)+', "ababababab")
['ababababab']
```

Why does this happen?

---

Sorry,i may not speak my question clearly

(?:ab) takes 'ab' as a whole ,let's make c=ab,so c+=ababab....

so this is clearly

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:ab)+', "ababababab") <br>
['ababababab']
```

my question is that why does this happen:

```
>>> match=re.search(r'(ab)+', "ababababab") <br>
>>> match.group()<br>
'ababababab'
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think I am missing the question here. Can someone whoe understands it make it clear?

Comment: Edited for clarity with examples.

Answer (score 6):

I think the question you are asking here is why does it return this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(ab)+', "ababababab")
['ab']
```

The answer is that if you have one or more groups in the pattern then findall will return a list with all the matched groups.  However your regex has one group that is matched multiple times within the regex, so it takes the last value of the match.

I think what you want is either this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(ab)', "ababababab")
['ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab']
```

or the version you posted:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:ab)+', "ababababab")
['ababababab']
```

Comment: And to clarify further, `r'(?:ab)+'` doesn't contain a group, and when the pattern has no groups, `re.findall` returns a list containing the entire matched text.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern contains a group, findall returns the group rather than the entire match. Here (ab)+ matches the entire string, but only the group (ab) is returned.